# $httpprovider causing "Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined" error

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app with a node/express backend. Ive attempted to implement an authentication interceptor using httpProvider. When there is a token stored in local storage the application works as expected and I am able to retrieve restricted data from the backend, but as soon as I delete the token by logging out and attempt to redirect to the main view, I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined. If I comment out the line of code in the config were Ive registered the interceptor the error is gone. For some reason that I have not been able to diagnose, the application crashes unless there is a token in local storage.

[image]

Authentication Interceptor:

```
angular.module('barmehealth')
  .factory('authInterceptor', function(authToken) {

    return {
      request: function(config) {
        var token = authToken.getToken();

        if (token)  {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

          return config;
        }
      },
      response: function(response) {
       return response;
      }
    };
  });
```

Registered in the Config object:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

I attempted to fix the problem by changing the code as follows:

```
.factory('authInterceptor', function(authToken) {

  return {
    request: function(config) {
      var currentToken = authToken.getToken();
      var token = currentToken ? currentToken : null;

      if (token)  {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

        return config;
      }
    },
    response: function(response) {
      return response;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your auth interceptor only conditionally returns `config`. This is a logical error. Fix it like this:

```
request: function(config) {
  var token = authToken.getToken();

  if (token)  {
     config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
  }

  return config;
}
```

It's important not to put your only `return` statement inside of an `if` block. Otherwise, if there is no token, no config will be returned and things will get hairy.

The error is being thrown because when there is no token and `config` is not returned, the angular `serverRequest` method tries to access `config.headers` and finds that `config` is undefined because you didn't return it.

Comment: Oh man, what a bonehead mistake. Thank you, obviously it works as expected.